# Can't drag vertical scrollbar, IE6 and IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, scrollbar

I've set `overflow:auto` on a div with a set height and I get a default scrollbar which is just what I would expect. The problem is, when I look at this in IE 6 or IE 7 I can't drag the scrollbar down to reveal more content. The down and up arrows above and below the scrollbar work and so does the mouse wheel but not the bar proper.

Anyone ever had this happen to them or know of a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a local issue.
If no other computers act like this, you don't need to worry.

If, however, other computers act the same, investigate whether there is anything overlapping your scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it on some other machines but I don't think it has any other elements overlapping the scrollbar as I can still interact with the buttons etc at the top and bottom of it.